# unwanted output with ConTeXt mode settings

Tags: context

I am trying to use ConTeXt modes to prepare some text on two displays: screen and print.

```
\enablemode[screen]
\startmode[screen]
\setuppapersize[S6][S6]
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
\definefontfeature[default][default][onum=yes]
\definefontfamily[biolinum][sans][Linux Biolinum O]
\setuptolerance[verytolerant,stretch] 
\setupbodyfont[biolinum,20pt]%[features=onum]
\stopmode[screen]

\startnotmode[screen]
   \setuppapersize[A4][A4]
   \setuppagenumbering[state=start]
   \setupcolors[state=stop]
   \setupbodyfont[biolinum,12pt]
   \setuptolerance[strict]
\stopnotmode[screen]


\starttext

Here's my first presentation in \CONTEXT!

\stoptext
```

When I compile my MWE, I have an unwanted output `[screen]`.

[image]

I read carefully ConTeXt reference manual and search the web, but cannot figure why is my output wrong. I tried to introduce several times `\enablemode[screen]` but it didn't change the output at all. I'm pretty sure I didn't understand something when reading the man and the wiki.

Comment: I am not sure which wiki page were you reading, but this is explained in detail on the page on [modes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes)

Comment: Oh, I read several of them (modes, presentation, handout and so on), but those stop errors were too obvious to be noticed. Shame on me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two environments to include and exclude commands with modes have the form

```
\startmode[...]
  ...
\stopmode
```

and

```
\startnotmode[...]
  ...
\stopnotmode
```

where only the start-command takes a argument with the name of the mode but not the stop-command.

Comment: Indeed, the same is true of all (?) ConTeXt's start-stop commands: the start might (often does) accept some options, but the stop doesn't. It's a bit like XML tags in that way.